# Data is not loading at JqGrid in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, jqgrid

Data is not getting loaded in JqGrid from controller in ASP.NET Core.
I tried two ways, you can see two different methods in controller which I tried.
What am I doing wrong?

**Index.cshtml**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url:'@Url.Action("Index", "Maintenance")',
                mtype: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Badge', name: 'Badge', key: true, width: 75 },
                    { label: 'User ID', name: 'User', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'EmailAddress', name: 'EmailAddress', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'FULL_NAME_PREFERRED', name: 'FULL_NAME_PREFERRED', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'Active', name: 'Active', width: 150 }
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 780,
                height: 250,
                rowNum: 20,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

**MaintenanceController**
**Way 1**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var lstMaintenanceModels = repos.GetUsers();         
             return View(lstMaintenanceModels);
        }
```

**Way 2**

```
  public JsonResult Index()
            {
                var lstMaintenanceModels = repos.GetUsers();         
                return Json(lstMaintenanceModels);
               
            }
```

**Starup.cs**

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });
```

**Output what i am getting right now**

**Way 1**
[image]

**Way 2**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to write all js code in `@section Scripts{}`, Because the key in the json returned by the controller is lowercase, and what you wrote here is uppercase, it cannot be received. So in page you need to wirte like this :

The page needs to receive the value of json type, so you need to use the second method, or return the model directly, the program will automatically serialize it to json.

[image]

**Code**

```
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" integrity="sha512-xAIWSSbGucVRdutqUD0VLDowcMF/K8W87EbIoa9YUYB4bTyt/zeykyuu9Sjp0TPVdgrgGgBVCBowKv46wY5gDQ==" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/plugins/css/ui.multiselect.min.css" integrity="sha512-UuhJihFIXhnP4QEzaNXfLmzY9W3xoeTDATm0buV4wb2qJKoikNn568f0zA5QmrX0sp6VZzqE6fffvsTYU34tGA==" rel="stylesheet"></link>
 

<table id="dataTable"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
 

@section Scripts
{
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha512-xt9pysburfYgFvYEtlhPDo8qBEPsupsDvWB8+iwspD+oQTvAdDEpA1aIKcH6zuABU528YitH6jtP0cAe5GrwKA==" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
    jQuery("#dataTable").jqGrid({
    url:'@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Home")',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    //here name must be 
    colModel: [
                    { label: 'Badge', name: 'badge', key: true, width: 75 },
                    { label: 'User ID', name: 'user', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'EmailAddress', name: 'emailAddress', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'FULL_NAME_PREFERRED', name: 'fulL_NAME_PREFERRED', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'Active', name: 'active', width: 150 }
                ],
               loadonce: true,
                width: 780,
                height: 250,
                rowNum: 20,
                pager: "#pager"
                
});

</script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Response- Xinran Shen, but still after modifying my code 1.adding js inside @section 2.Making everything in lowercase I am getting same output. Is that some config or anything I am missing

Comment: Did you lowercase the name I mentioned above? I think that's the main reason, I am not use local js and link, I edit my answer to show the js and link whitch i used

Comment: yes,I am using lowercase in mentioned section.I was also trying to use that link and js you have used now getting below error **parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 200 parsererror** Is that any error in my controller method (right now using way 1).On using way 2 same output was comming

Comment: sorry, I ignored you set AddNewtonsoftJson in startup.cs, So you don't need to  using lowercase in your code, I don't understand why you get this error after using the js and link i provided,  and return json to page directly. Can you provide your .net core version and jquery version?

Comment: Did you change some other configuration?

Comment: No I have not change any other configuration. And I am using .Net 5.0 core and JQgrid 4.4 which i install from nuget package manager.

Comment: @Amrita Verma, I check the `JQgrid` package in npm, But i am not sure it can apply to .Net core, So i think you need to use F12 to Make sure to reference the css and js I provide and not the local one. Can you provide  the json in the image as code style, I need to check if there is some error in it.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter datatype is 'json', jqGrid expects the following default format for JSON data

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
  ]
}
```

You can read about this there^
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data

Try this:

```
return Json(new { rows = repos.GetUsers() } );
```